# How To Create This Type of Structure?

Tags: android, xml

How to create this ? I tried .May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?
  I want to create this .

```
Textview In center

    Seek Bar   TextView
       "        TextView
       "        TextView
       "       TextView
       "        TextView
```

Here is my XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.example.androidtesting.VerticalSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/verticalSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="5"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" 

        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fivemore"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/threetofour" 
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/onetotwo" 
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/onceamonth" 
            android:textSize="25sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/specialevents" 
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: a cusmized listview with TextView ?

Comment: You can check out my answer, I edited it, you can put your fields in the layouts and it should work fine.

Comment: @Kedarnath Sir: Not .

Comment: @Lunchbox Sorry not working right now

Comment: @Amiya, Yes are right, I am not sir. Fresher like you :)

Comment: @Kedarnath But your experience /reputation shows your value

Comment: @Amiya, see this [example link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/) , now remove image and second Textview from it's .xml, then you will get your code :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your structure, and I think you're not far away to achieve this. I made just few changes and commented it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- set id + align parent top to true -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- below the id text_header + weightSum to 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weigthSum="1" >

        <!-- layout weight to 0.5 + width to 0 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.androidtesting.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/verticalSeekbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="5"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
                android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- layout weight to 0.5 + width to 0 + weightSum to 5 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <!-- layout weight to 1 + height to 0 + text center vertical -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/fivemore"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <!-- same as above... -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/threetofour" 
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/onetotwo" 
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/onceamonth" 
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/specialevents" 
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure but this should give you the expected behaviour. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Text in center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right side" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seekbar have one column & total textview another & it divided by 5 rows

Comment: You can just add your vertical seekbar where I added the normal seekbar, and add the anount of textviews you want where I added one textview. They will display below one another. Copy and paste it, then you can play around with it to see what I mean

Comment: Oh wait, do you mean one textview per seekbar? Sorry, I dont really get it

Comment: Create a picture in paint to explain how you want it?